# How to share video file allocated in Raw folder Android

Tags: android, video, share, android-resources

In the app, I have a fragment where I play a videos. This videos are allocated in `../res/raw/<video.mp4>`

To play the video I generate the path to it like:

```
this.videoPath = "android.resource://" + requireContext().packageName + "/" + args.videoId
```

where "args.videoId" is the id from the video generated using:

```
val packageName: String = context.packageName
val videoId = context.resources.getIdentifier(<video_name>, "raw", packageName) // video name for example "video1"
```

With all this stuff I can play the video using `VideoView`.

But the **problem** arrives when I have to share the video file to other apps like telegram/whatsapp... etc.

To do it, I launch an intent like:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
val uri = Uri.parse(this.videoPath)

intent.apply {
   type = "*/*"
   putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
}

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sharing Video:"))
```

The problem is that when I select the app to share I'm getting errorss.

For example in Telegram I get:

"Realpath failed for "dandroid.resource://com.mypackage.myapp/"

If I try to send via WhatsApp is sent something like a "file":

[image]

So , how can I share the mp4 file of the video?

Comment: Yes that android.resource cannot be used here. You should implement a ContentProvider to serve from raw. This has been done before.

Comment: https://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2012/03/too-easy-using-contentprovider-to-send.html

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look to it.